# Who invented syntax highlighting (and when)?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, history

Who invented syntax highlighting (and when)?

I tried searching on web, but could not find definite answer.

Wikipedia mentions something along line "One of first editors with syntax highlighting was..."

PS. I hope this is right stackexchange site for this question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the right SE site for this question. But see the History section of this [Wikipedia article on syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting).

I first came across it in 1984 with Business Basic on the [Nixdorf 8870](http://www.8870adventures.com/who-were-nixdorf.html).